# Conceptual Query -- C# 4.0, ASPX.NET, GUI

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I am looking for honest / constructive feedback.

I hear a lot of my peers who have been using .NET for a while now, say how easily they built their GUI interfaces. On closer inspection they have used 3rd party tools such as Infragistics.

As a new .NET programmer (certified I may add), I wanted to know if anyone has actually created interfaces using nothing but what ever happens to be available by default with the framework...

I am guessing it shouldn't be too difficult to create a good, aethestic looking GUI without using 3rd party addons.

Comment: you refer to website UI? Its all about css. Nothing special. Of cause you can do everything with the standard controls, it is even possible to create cool web UIs with html, css and some images only :p It really depends on what you want, and ur question is just to broad to really answer that...

Comment: Try to separate the idea of ASP.NET from the user interface.  Your user interface for a web application should primarily be based on JS/CSS in which case you probably want to use some free 3rd party tools like jQuery to make a nice UI.  There are plenty of free tools available.

Comment: Not good for SO as it purely opinion based... But it is *very-very-very* "difficult to create a good, aethestic looking GUI" irrespective if you use any framework/3rd party controls/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes We've done it (windows).

Depends on where you put the emphasis in your guess. No its not TOO difficult, but it's definitely not easy, unless your requirements are truly trivial, as opposed to apparently trivial.

All depends on what you need / want to do. My advice don't tell your boss, this will be easy, well not unless you want help getting out of the door for the last time.

For instance take a straight textbox.

They want to enter currency in it.

- Multiple rounding algorithms.

  Enter raw value display formatted, Currency symbol, thousand
  separators.

  Optional pounds or pence.

  Optional blank or zero

  Optional treatment of negatives.

  Optional display formatting of negatives.

  Alignment on decimal point.

  Auto change of font on resizing.

  And break none of the standard behaviours.

Trust me not simple at all. Especially if you do something Infragistics did not, and go for a good developer interface as well as the end user behaviours.

Not trying to put you off. It's challenging and rewarding, but when you have the entire application stuck behind some irritating bug in the UI, bosses lose patience real quick and you haven't got that get out of jail free card in shrugging and saying that's how X works.

NB just buying a suite won't fix all these problems, you can spend a lot of time producing a totally crap UI with them as well, just you don't have to write the code...

The answer to that is a lot of hard work. :(

Can your current suite be upgraded?

If you have the source could it be fixed, if you had the source and it's been twiddled with, are those "improvements" interfering?

Needs some hard-headed realistic analysis this. Which components are broke? How much are they used? How much of the extra behaviour in the suite do you really need.

Most important, how good is your separation of concerns in the current code, and how comprehensive both unit tests and automation tests.

Would compatibility mode sort it out?

Need to get to a point where the number of questions doesn't significantly out weigh the number of answers.

I've been where you are though it was another suite in another environment. The people looking for the cheap, quick and painless way of dealing with a mess like this were hugely disappointed, but it can be attacked in parts as long as everybody takes a heavy dose of pragmatism. 
As a for instance,

Someone had bought a windows component that looked like a html link, and was heavily dependent on File associations and API calls. It was very visible and all over the place, I knocked up a much better and far less fragile one in a few days, swapped it in, a lot of perceived problems disappeared, confidence increased, and the remaining problems started to look less horrible.

Think of it like going into triage mode on bugs at the end of a struggling release.

Comment: Wonderful response... you have pretty much outlined everything I am trying to resolve. As it turns out, an application that we converted to 4.0 about a year back is now in deep **** since the 3rd party software we used won't work in a Win7 environment... My first thought was -- why not do it with native tools?
You have definitely pointed the pitfalls.

@ Ela and the others -- the question was more "how do I solve this?" not so much "how do I code this?"... :) Appreciate all your inputs, will try and see how it pans out.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll add a bit more